# Google Navigation (Android 1.6) intent callback

Tags: android, gps

I'm using intents to launch Google Navigation:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=" + location)); 
startActivity(i);
```

`location` is a string with GPS coordinates.

Google Navigation pops up nicely and plots the route. Can they return some type of callback when the user has reached their destination? Any way of implementing `startActivityForResult()`?

If not, what would be my best bet? I've been considering running a service in the background that keeps tabs on the location and ending Google Navigation and returning to my app when the GPS registers that it's near the destination (because I know the latitude/longitude).

Thanks folks

Comment: Can you give more details on how you build location string? I tried lat+long and long+lat and navigation won't recognize it.

Comment: @katit: It was undocumented at the time, don't know about now. This has some info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662531/launching-google-maps-directions-via-an-intent-on-android, but my best advice is to try `lat,lon` where `lat` and `lon` are your coordinates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wanted to post how I managed to get this to work. I'm not using activity callbacks, but I am starting a service with a `LocationManager` hanging out in it. When the user gets close to the destination coordinates, I just terminate Google Navigation and start my activity back up.

Comment: That is exactly what I've been trying for the last hours :) Can you please provide some sample code?

Comment: Yes can you please post some guidance on how to do this?

Comment: You may have an easier time using GeoFences - https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html