# Android - launch google map via web url

Tags: android, browser, android-intent

On the iPhone, a maps.google.com URL is intercepted and loaded by the native google maps application. I would like do the same on Android, but Google Maps is being loaded in the browser.

So, in a web page, is it possible to have this url http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=brighton&daddr=timbuktu open in the Android Google Map application ?

I see from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662531/launching-google-maps-directions-via-an-intent-on-android) question that you can do it from another app via an Intent. Can you trigger these Intent's from the browser ?

**Edit** - On further testing, I've found that the user will be prompted to open the link in browser or map app for standard html links to maps.google.maps :

```
<a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=brighton&daddr=timbuktu">show route</a>
```

I'm having the problem because I'm using javascript to set the window.location.href via a Location API callback (so I can get the user's location and then open the map).  I've opened a [bug report](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13888) for this.

Comment: Note that since iOS 6, you have to convert all map requests from "maps.google.com" to "maps.apple.com" for the iOS map to activate. Rather annoying really.

Comment: There is another question (for Android devices) that is related to this question that I also found helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8443662/google-maps-link-produces-slightly-moved-marker-when-opened-with-native-iphone-a

Answer (score 15):

Typing geo:0,0?q=google into the address bar opens the maps activity and searches for google nearby.

I assume this will work from a link in a page, but haven't checked.

a full list of accessible intents here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html

Comment: Strangely, that isn't working on Nexus One.  And even if it did, the geo URI doesn't currently support saddr/daddr parameters. (http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-mayrhofer-geo-uri-00)

Comment: I tested with a link in a page, and it does work on Nexus One (you just can't type it into the URL bar).  I any case, I still can't use it for getting directions.

Comment: Strange, I can type it into the browser address bar on my HTC. Anyway, in terms of directions, there's the unreliable `google.navigation:q=starbucks` intent, but I hear it's not available everywhere.

Comment: Yes, it works on Nexus One with when embedded into hyperlink: <a href="geo:50,30">Test</a>

Comment: Support for this is dismal at best. My research has netted nothing of value, any other ideas out there?

Answer (score 11):

At this moment I use a javascript function that change the following templates:

```
'urlTemplates': {
            "default": "http://maps.google.com?q={streetAddress} {addressLocality} {addressRegion} {postalCode} {addressCountry}",
            "ios": "maps:?saddr=Current Location&daddr={streetAddress} {addressLocality} {addressRegion} {postalCode} {addressCountry}",
            "android": "geo:{streetAddress} {addressLocality} {addressRegion} {postalCode} {addressCountry}",
            "windows_phone7": "maps:{streetAddress} {addressLocality} {addressRegion} {postalCode} {addressCountry}",
            "windows_phone8": "bingmaps:?where={streetAddress} {addressLocality} {addressRegion} {postalCode} {addressCountry}",
            "blackberry": "javascript:blackberry.launch.newMap({'address':{'address1':'{streetAddress}','city':'{addressLocality}','country':'{addressCountry}','stateProvince':'{addressRegion}','zipPostal':'{postalCode}'}});"
```

with what informations I got depending on the device, I do not remember from where I got all the templates and I am sorry for that, and after that I open the the address using window.location.href.

Hope this will help you. Because at the time I need this I spent a lot of time researching it.

Answer (score 7):

```
<html>
  <body>
  <H1>
   <a href="geo:42,2?z=8">Click here for maps</a>
 </h1>
   <BR><BR>
   <a href="geo:53,-9?saddr=(53,-9)&daddr=(42,4)">Click here for route maps</a>
 </body>
</html>
```

The first click correctly loads the Google App on Android and zooms. In the second click I an trying to replicate a two point route (start address->destination address) and it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 5):

I really suffered a lot from this but finally got answer .
**Don't use href** , it will not work .

For Navigation -
window.open("google.navigation:q=23.3728831,85.3372199&mode=d" , '_system');

For Search - 
window.open("geo:0,0?q=pizza" , '_system');

Read Here - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/intents

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this link and it works just fine

```
<a href='https://www.google.com/maps/place/{{device?.gps_lat}},{{device?.gps_long}}' target="_blank">
```