# Open native map app with Phonegap

Tags: cordova

Hi I am in the process of learning phonegap , and I have a request from a client that asked me that when a link with an address is clicked the internal mapps app should open.In case of android that may be google maps app and in case of iOS the apple maps app.

After a bit of searching I found this plugin for phonegap [WebIntent](http://smus.com/android-phonegap-plugins/) with it seems I will be able to open native apps.All the examples I found online are for android.And from what I understand they use an internal android component called intent.

My question is has anyone tryed this plugin on iOS?

Comment: try this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9688607/how-to-open-a-mobile-devices-map-app-when-a-user-clicks-on-a-link/14352081#14352081