# creating button opens default appp - react webview

Tags: reactjs, webview

I'm creating React app which will be implemented on webview from some other app.
I need to create a button, onClick it will be open default map application on the phone, with pinned provided adress. I found nothing about it. Could someone help me please?

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9688607/how-to-open-a-mobile-devices-map-app-when-a-user-clicks-on-a-link

Comment: thank you! this article was very helpful https://medium.com/@colinlord/opening-native-map-apps-from-the-mobile-browser-afd66fbbb8a4