# Google Map in mobile devices

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, google-maps

In my app, I've used map like `http://maps.google.com/maps?q=`

The problem is that Android has a label “A” but iPhone has the address. when I tap the Pin label to “get Directions” in iPhone, the page does contain the actual street address, but Android doesn't.

As far as I know, iPhone has its own app in order to display map, but Android displays in the browser.

Is there any way to manage Android`s map?

Comment: Try to avoid putting "Thanks in Advance" at the end of your questions. For a little detail about such things have a look at the following post of meta [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Answer (score 1):

I think Android has a different way of hotlinking addresses:

Use the following code:

```
<html>
  <body>
  <H1>
   <a href="geo:42,2?z=8">Click here for maps</a>
 </h1>
   <BR><BR>
   <a href="geo:53,-9?saddr=(53,-9)&daddr=(42,4)">Click here for route maps</a>
 </body>
</html>
```

via https://stackoverflow.com/a/6299564/580173