# Android, draw route on google map

Tags: android, api, google-maps, geolocation, google-directions-api

In my android project I want to draw route on Google maps. I have coordinates of start and end points. On this points I get `km`-file  from Google web service with points witch across route. For drawing parts of route I use instances of `Overlay` class. And this solution works, but very slowly. Are there another methods to do that? May be exists ability use built-in Google maps application or any another way?

Comment: I think, that's the only option you got a the moment.

Answer (score 10):

Right, you can use the  built-in google maps application via an intent like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=20.344,34.34&daddr=20.5666,45.345"));
startActivity(intent);
```

see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662531/launching-google-maps-directions-via-an-intent-on-android) for more details

Answer (score 2):

there's a tutorial for using KML here:
http://csie-tw.blogspot.com/2009/06/android-driving-direction-route-path.html

and some sample code here:
[How to draw a path on a map using kml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109158/how-to-draw-a-path-on-a-map-using-kml-file/3109723#3109723)

it all looks like a lot of overly-complicated hard work - Google should provide API's for this instead.