# Opening native map application from url in iPhone, Android, Blackberry

Tags: iphone, android, blackberry, maps

I was trying to open the native map application to show direction from Current Location to the given location. Understandably, the url should work on all the smart phones, not just iPhone.

The most common url that can be used for all the phones can be maps.google.com.

For iPhone I have used http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=Current%20Location&daddr=lat,lon. It works perfectly fine, iPhone opens the map with my Current Location and the destination location and draws direction. But it doesn't work on other devices.

Any suggestion ?

Thanks.

Comment: refer this for android: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205827/how-to-open-standard-google-map-application-from-my-application

Comment: just detect the user agent and based on that serve a platform-specific url

Answer (score 0):

I've written a blog post addressing this topic and how open native map apps, not just the google site. Check it out here : http://habaneroconsulting.com/insights/Opening-native-map-apps-from-the-mobile-browser.aspx

Comment: Fixed URL: http://habaneroconsulting.com/insights/Opening-native-map-apps-from-the-mobile-browser.aspx