# geo:latitude,longitude?z=zoom in android taking me to my current location

Tags: android, maps, location, coordinates

I want to call the inbuilt map app from my app. I came across [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205827/how-to-open-standard-google-map-application-from-my-application). this page also gave me [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html) where I could really get what I want. I know

```
geo:latitude,longitude?z=zoom
```

is still in development mode.

My problem is that when ever I use this it takes to the desired location but then diverts me to my current location.

Here is the piece code I am using it

```
String uri = String.format("geo:%f,%f?z=18",(float)(latitude /1E6),(float)(longitude/1E6));
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
startActivity(intent);
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: what is lat and long value also can you paste your code

Comment: Provide Sufficient code and you'll get a solution

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one.....

```
Intent mapintent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q="+lat_string+long_string+"(Title_to_show)"));
```

Where `lat_string` and `long_string` are in there original format i.e `76.6464831` `35.494` something..