# How do i link my android app to another built in application like google maps?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, onclick

I would like to know if i can link my application with a app like google maps? For example If i create a button and `onClick` I go to Google maps app.So is there a way i can direct the `onClick` event of the button directly to the maps?If so how do I do it?

Comment: Have you checked the answers listed here?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662531/launching-google-maps-directions-via-an-intent-on-android

Comment: see this if it helps

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205827/how-to-open-standard-google-map-application-from-my-application

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with intents, if you want to open google maps from your app, you can do it with this code:

```
String uri = "geo:"+ latitude + "," + longitude;
Intent myMapIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
startActivity(myMapIntent);
```

You can find some useful info about that in the [related Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
geo:latitude,longitude
geo:latitude,longitude?z=zoom
geo:0,0?q=my+street+address
geo:0,0?q=business+near+city
```

From the [Android Developer guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr="+mylocation));
startActivity(intent);
```