# Redirect user to Google Maps Android application to show a direction

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2, android-maps

I am working in an android application and I have two Geo points. I want the user to redirect to the google map android application from my application to show the directions in the map. How can I pass the two geopoints to google map android application to show the direction in the google map application.

Comment: This has been already answered =)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205827/how-to-open-standard-google-map-application-from-my-application

Comment: Thanks for the response, but the given link shows only a location in the google map. I want to show a direction.

Answer (score 13):

[Here's an example showing directions in the Google Maps app](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2663565/716588) using an intent.

From the linked answer:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=20.344,34.34&daddr=20.5666,45.345"));
startActivity(intent);
```