# Open Google Map with markers within Google Maps App

Tags: javascript, android, ios, google-maps

I've used the Google Maps JavaScript API to put a bunch of markers on a map, within a web page. I'd like to allow users to choose to open the map, with markers, within the Google Maps app, should they have it on their device.

Currently the markers, when clicked, display the name of the location and some other details. I'd like to maintain this functionality within the app too.

Is there an easy way to achieve this? I'm a front-end web developer with a decent amount of JS experience, but I don't have any experience developing iOS or Android apps, and I was hoping there'd be an easy solution within the API, but haven't come across an answer. There's a good chance that this simply isn't possible due to the differences between the web and app platforms, but I just don't know.

Answer (score 0):

This is a built-in feature of the Google Maps `iOS` (and thus I assume Android) API. In the `iOS` API, add the following entry in `Info.plist` file:

```
LSApplicationQueriesSchemes
    Item 0... String... googlechromes
    Item 1... String... comgooglemaps
```

And then whenever a marker is tapped in the app, if the user then taps the Google attribution logo (usually at the bottom of the screen), the Google Maps app will open that marker. These entries allow for that to happen.

The Android guys can speak to Android but I'm sure it's as simple, if not simpler. Here are some methods: [How to open standard Google Map application from my application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205827/how-to-open-standard-google-map-application-from-my-application)