# Direct open GoogleMap from clicking on a MapView

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-mapview

I have an application that use a MapView to display a pin to a location.
I would like to open Google Map to this pin when clicking the map view.

I've done the following from my activity

```java
this.map.setClickable(true);
this.map.getMapAsync(this);

...

public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
        LatLng position= new LatLng(this.model.getLatitude(), this.model.getLongitude()); 
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(position).title(this.model.getLabel()));
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(position, 15));
    }
```

But it does not open google map directly instead it show me the following buttons
[image]

I would rather open directly google map instead.
How can I do it ?

Comment: What "I would rather open directly google map instead" means? Do you want to open Google Maps application in the location of that marker?

Comment: @MatiasLappalainen Yes the idea is to open the map to the marker position without having to use the bottom right buttons, just by a click on the map

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205827/how-to-open-standard-google-map-application-from-my-application) answer your question?