# Using Android's native Sat Nav app in your own app?

Tags: android, mobile, cordova, sencha-touch

Sorry if I sound too naive.

We intend to develop a native app using Phonegap and Sencha Touch. One of the requirements are to have a Sat Nav feature in where you could give a post code and it will guide you to there. However, I assume that feature is too costly to develop at it's own and would also mean we would be making a wheel of our own. The thought is and this is the actual question, if we could invoke Android's native Sat Nav (that comes built-in) from our app.

If anyone can help, I will be grateful, also if you guys have any other ideas, kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any way of doing this using the built in Google Maps application, and I'd avoid using it anyway (it doesn't have offline map storage, so if you drive into an area with no mobile coverage you lose navigation).  But there are a couple of APIs you can purchase to do this kind of thing: http://www.copilotlive.com/uk/enterprise/ and http://www.sygic.com/en/business:buy-now both appear to be able to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean launching the Google Maps app with directions, look here

https://stackoverflow.com/q/2663565/984393

Basically you send a request in the form of an Intent for android to star the maps application.