# Suppress chooser dialog when calling Google map using intent

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to call google map intent without showing "Complete Action Dialog"?

Is it possible? Here is my code.

```
String uri = "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + Utils.getLatitude(ShowDetails.this)+","+Utils.getLongitude(ShowDetails.this)+"&daddr="+userLatitude+","+userLongitude;
startActivity(new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_DEFAULT, Uri.parse(uri)));
```

I dont want to show below dialog when calling google map intent . Any Help is appreciated .

[image]

Comment: Related: [Launching Google Maps Directions via an intent on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2662531)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Below code helps me to solve my question.

```
String uri = "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + Utils.getLatitude(ShowDetails.this)+","+Utils.getLongitude(ShowDetails.this)+"&daddr="+userLatitude+","+userLongitude;
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thank you , it helped me too much , but what if want to add more than a place to the map ,? do you have an idea?

Answer (score 6):

Use the Google Maps URI rather than "http://[...] "

It goes something like this:

```
String uri = "geo:" + latitude + "," + longitude
```

Check out http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html for the info.

Comment: what is the uri for showing driving direction on google map ?

Comment: You can try placing the necessary info after the '?' of `geo:0,0?q=my+street+address` and see if that works.

Comment: can you give me example using above my string uri in question .

Comment: I'm not sure if I can; I really have no idea if the geo uri will work the way you'd like it to. I would just try a few different things to see if they'd work. 

Maybe try adding everything after the ? in the http uri.

Also, read more here:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662531/launching-google-maps-directions-via-an-intent-on-android

Answer (score 0):

Try **`ACTION_VIEW`** instead of `ACTION_DEFAULT`:

```
String uri = "geo:"+ latitude + "," + longitude;
startActivity(new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri)));
```

check this Android doc [Intents List](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html) and browse to "Google Maps".

Comment: @ChiragRaval dear its not working fine here. I have tested in my phone as to check your comment.