# open google maps native app directly

Tags: android

I kinda need your help.
so I have this data
longitude = 6.97425
latitude = -107.63164
which I retrieve from database, and i want my app to open google maps native app directly and show me the location from that latitude and longitude.
I have no idea how to do that. maybe you can help me, thank

pardon my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

Try reading this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8132069/calling-google-map-using-intent). You have to basically fire up an intent with corresponding action for google maps application.