# Generate Googlemaps with address string

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

I am pretty new to the Google API.
I have in my database some addresses information stored and I am calling it to my page with a PHP while loop.
What I would like is that it shows the location of the address in Googlemaps based on street name and city stored in database.

The only way I see how to use Google maps is with latitude and longitude. Is there a way to convert the street name and city into these coordinates so it generate correct maps location on my website?

I hope someone can provide me with an answer. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Check [geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding). You can use an address to get location of it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps API - Get Coordinates of address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652951/google-maps-api-get-coordinates-of-address)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a PHP solution that generates the lat and lng that works for me. Hopefully also for you.

```
// Get the JSON 
$url='http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=2+bis+avenue+Foch75116+Paris+FR&sensor=false';
$source = file_get_contents($url);
$obj = json_decode($source);
$lat = $obj->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
$lng = $obj->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
echo $lat;
```

It generates a JSON with the address and with PHP you can get the lat and lng.
Just add your address in the $url string after "address="

Answer (score 0):

Use http://maps.google.com/maps?q= and add the adress string at the end of the url.

If you want to use it for mobile look at the question. [Suppress chooser dialog when calling Google map using intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8132069/suppress-chooser-dialog-when-calling-google-map-using-intent)