# Is it possible to use Uri.Builder and not have the "//" part?

Tags: android, uri

I am trying to build a `mailto:` uri to send a mail using the GMail app.
I would like to use the `android.net.Uri.Builder` class to do this, but the resulting uri is in the form `mailto://test@example.com`, which makes the GMail app think the recipient is `//test@example.com`, instead of just `test@example.com`.

I ended up doing this:

```
String uriStr = uriBuilder.toString();
uriStr = uriStr.replaceAll("//", "");
final Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriStr);
```

but clearly, this is an ugly hack...

Is there no way to build the uri without the `//` part?

Comment: Here it is @Blundell:

    final Builder uriBuilder = new Builder();
    uriBuilder.scheme("mailto");
    uriBuilder.authority(recipient);
    uriBuilder.appendQueryParameter("subject", subject);
    uriBuilder.appendQueryParameter("body", body);
    String uriStr = uriBuilder.toString();

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are several issues here. While it is possible to get rid of the `//` part, you will loose the query strings then. The main problem is that Uri.Builder won't let you use queries with opaque URIs (an opaque URI is an absolute URI whose scheme-specific part does not begin with a slash character, like `mailto:` URIs).

That said, you should use `uriBuilder.opaquePart()` instead of `uriBuilder.authority()` because the latter [implicitly sets your URI to hierarchical](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/net/Uri.java#Uri.Builder.authority%28android.net.Uri.Part%29), i.e. non-opaque. This will get rid of the `//`, but you're lacking the query part then, and you cannot set it, because any call to `uriBuilder.appendQueryParameter()` also [implies a hierarchical URI](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/net/Uri.java#Uri.Builder.appendQueryParameter%28java.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.String%29).

Long story short, to construct an opaque `mailto:` URI that includes queries, you'll have to use

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("mailto:receipient@mail.com?subject=title&body=text");
```

instead. Of course, the literal `title` and `text` should be `Uri.encode()`ed.

Answer (score 6):

The answer given by sschuberth is a good explanation of what's going on, but as a more practical answer (you *do* want to properly escape parameters, etc. after all), I used two builders to get around this:

```
Builder builder1 = new Builder();
builder1.scheme("mailto");
builder1.opaquePart(emailAddress);

Builder builder2 = new Builder();
builder2.appendQueryParameter("subject", subject);
builder2.appendQueryParameter("body", body);

Uri uri = Uri.parse(builder1.toString() + builder2.toString());
```

You probably don't want to do this in a tight loop with millions of addresses, but for general use I think this should be fine.

Comment: I always prefer contact whenever there are two strings `builder1.toString().concat(builder2.toString())`

Answer (score 0):

[sschuberth's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12035226/238753) is much briefer than [kabuko's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14992042/238753), so here's a variant that also covers encoding:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(
    String.format("mailto:%s?subject=%s",
        Uri.encode(recipient),
        Uri.encode(subject)
    )
);
```