# Send Email Intent

Tags: android, email, android-intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/html");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "emailaddress@emailaddress.com");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "I'm email body.");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send Email"));
```

The above code opens a dialog showing the following apps:- Bluetooth, Google Docs, Yahoo Mail, Gmail, Orkut, Skype, etc.

Actually, I want to filter these list options. I want to show only email-related apps e.g. Gmail, and Yahoo Mail. How to do it?

I've seen such an example on the 'Android Market application.

1. Open the Android Market app
2. Open any application where the developer has specified his/her email address. (If you can't find such an app just open my app:- market://details?id=com.becomputer06.vehicle.diary.free, OR search by 'Vehicle Diary')
3. Scroll down to 'DEVELOPER'
4. Click on 'Send Email'

The dialog shows only email Apps e.g. Gmail, Yahoo Mail, etc. It does not show Bluetooth, Orkut, etc. What code produces such dialog?

Comment: Sorry, this is not possible with Intent.ACTION_SEND. Maybe it works with an intent directly to the gmail-App but I don't know if this is possible.

Comment: In case anyone happens to learn here about email intents, EXTRA_MAIL should correspond to a `String[]`, not just a `String` as shown here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Send email via gmail](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8284706/send-email-via-gmail)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Android Intent.ACTION\_SEND for sending email](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883199/using-android-intent-action-send-for-sending-email)

Comment: See here for some good advice: https://medium.com/@cketti/android-sending-email-using-intents-3da63662c58f

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to send emails from my Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197741/how-to-send-emails-from-my-android-application)

Comment: This did not work for me in 2020.
here if my working solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62877003/2155858

Answer (score 236, accepted):

when you will change your  intent.setType like below you will get

```
intent.setType("text/plain");
```

Use `android.content.Intent.ACTION_SENDTO` to get only the list of e-mail clients, with no facebook or other apps. Just the email clients.
Ex:

```
new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
```

I wouldn't suggest you get directly to the email app. Let the user choose his favorite email app. Don't constrain him.

If you use ACTION_SENDTO, putExtra does not work to add subject and text to the intent. Use Uri to add the subject and body text.

**EDIT:**
We can use `message/rfc822` instead of `"text/plain"` as the MIME type. However, that is not indicating "only offer email clients" -- it indicates "offer anything that supports message/rfc822 data". That could readily include some application that are not email clients.

`message/rfc822` supports MIME Types of `.mhtml, .mht, .mime`

Comment: Can you please provide some code to produce the desired output?

Comment: @becomputer06 refer this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8284706/send-email-via-gmail

Comment: The intent chooser says `no apps installed to perform this intent` when I use `ACTION_SENDTO`. I'm using Android 4.1.2 and I have an email app installed...

Comment: @ffleandro did you login the email app with your credentials.

Comment: The 'correct' way is the answer from Magnus. I recommend original poster to change the accepted answer.

Comment: Using the MIME type to perform a send operation is a bad idea, because you're basically instructing Android to provide a list of apps that support sending a file of type `message/rfc822`. That's **not** the same as sending an e-mail. Use the `mailto:` protocol instead, because that's what e-mail clients actually understand.

Comment: Answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/16217921/5245903 below is much much better and the correct answer.

Comment: worked but also need to add intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));

Comment: This did not work for me in 2020, here is my working solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62877003/2155858

Answer (score 984):

**UPDATE**

Official approach:

```
public void composeEmail(String[] addresses, String subject) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:")); // only email apps should handle this
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, addresses);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

[Ref link](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Email)

**OLD ANSWER**

The accepted answer doesn't work on the 4.1.2. This should work on all platforms:

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts(
            "mailto","abc@gmail.com", null));
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Body");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email..."));
```

Update: According to [marcwjj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1446995/marcwjj), it seems that on 4.3, we need to pass string array instead of a string for email address to make it work. We might need to add one more line:

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, addresses); // String[] addresses
```

Comment: You are right, and it doesn't either on 4.2. So this is actually the only correct answer, thanks!

Comment: This is perfect. Someone below mentioned that specifying the "mailto" part is what narrows the available options to email clients. Using Uri.fromParts("mailto", "", null) will put the cursor in the recipient field - perfect for what I needed.

Comment: is there a way to set the body with this?

Comment: Try this emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "I'm email body.");

Comment: In some circumstances, this caused an exception: "Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?" To fix that, at least this works:
`Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email...");
chooser.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(chooser);`

Comment: If you don't have a specific recipient, this also works: `Uri.fromParts("mailto", "", null)`

Comment: Is it possible to attach image?

Comment: You can try i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(pic)) and i.setType("image/png"), but you need to check on several OS versions as I had problem with attaching txt files, it worked on a version of OS, but would be different on the others

Comment: Why it doesn't work for me? I have installed email apps.

Comment: This does not work on my Android 4.3 any more. Please check out the official Android doc on sending email as intent, which works perfectly: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Email

Comment: Keep in mind that the EXTRA_EMAIL should allways be a String array, not a String with one address because that will be ignored.

Comment: You shouldn't create a chooser if you want the user to send the email directly to an email address of your choice. [Ref](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_CHOOSER) Instead you should just do `startActivity(emailIntent)`

Comment: This solution doesn't work with GMX Mail app. This one worked with every app I tested https://stackoverflow.com/a/17886006/1329901

Comment: Unfortunately this trusty old answer no longer works well (in recent Gmail versions?) — with this code, **subject & body are lost**. Right now, the best way seems to be Approach 2 from here: https://medium.com/better-programming/the-imperfect-android-send-email-action-59610dfd1c2d

Comment: `intent.resolveActivity()` gives warning see here:  https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility

Comment: Why MailTo doesn't appear in the Gmail in updated answer ?

Comment: this will work in all android os except android 12 os.

Comment: is there any changes in android 12 os for direct jump to email applications?

Comment: For API 30 or higher intent.resolveActivity(activity.getPackageManager()) == null.

You can remove that check in the if statement.

Checkout [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62856745/12143067)

Comment: Attention: while the updated code is still valid, starting from Android 11 (API30) you will need to declare a query in the manifest, so that it functions correctly. Please see: https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility/declaring and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62535856/intent-resolveactivity-returns-null-in-api-30/62856745#62856745 for details.

Answer (score 282):

There are three main approaches:

```
String email = /* Your email address here */
String subject = /* Your subject here */
String body = /* Your body here */
String chooserTitle = /* Your chooser title here */
```

**1. Custom `Uri`:**

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("mailto:" + email)
    .buildUpon()
    .appendQueryParameter("subject", subject)
    .appendQueryParameter("body", body)
    .build();

Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, chooserTitle));
```

**2. Using `Intent` extras:**

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse("mailto:" + email));
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);
//emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_HTML_TEXT, body); //If you are using HTML in your body text

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Chooser Title"));
```

**3. Support Library `ShareCompat`:**

```
Activity activity = /* Your activity here */

ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(activity)
    .setType("message/rfc822")
    .addEmailTo(email)
    .setSubject(subject)
    .setText(body)
    //.setHtmlText(body) //If you are using HTML in your body text
    .setChooserTitle(chooserTitle)
    .startChooser();
```

Comment: This worked much better for me - the other options popped up some straight things (Skype, for example) as possible handlers.

Comment: If you have a `%` symbol in the buffer, some characters in the resulting email won't be correctly encoded. You need to perform the `Uri.encode` dance suggested by @minipif.

Comment: This are the best answers here, don't waste your time trying others, the second one here is what i chose and it works perfectly, only showing the pure email apps, not gDrive, not bluetooth.. etc. Thanks @becomputer06

Comment: Be careful about "&"  character. If you got & character in email body, these method will cut off body after & . For example, 
if you send body like "I am & a sample body"  you will get just "I am"

Comment: For `SENDTO` (and using `URI.encode` if that's important) my phone doesn't show any apps to handle the intent. On `SEND` it does show Gmail and in the alternatives a lot more.

Comment: Beautiful answer. I knew the first two well but learned something new Specially the last one; about ShareCompat! Thank you

Comment: ShareCompat results in almost all the apps, not just email clients!

Comment: @Zelphir - that happened to me, too.  And none of these answers handle attachments.

Comment: The approach #2 works correctly and matches the docs. If you have no attachments, that's the right one. One thing - you can omit inluding recpieints emails in Uri.parse statement and pass them in extras of the intent, the way to do this is here: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Email

Comment: 3rd option with `.setType("message/rfc822")` gives me too much irrelevant options in Chooser dialog (Android 8.1). The good old `Intent.ACTION_SENDTO` approach works best!

Comment: On a Huawei P10: option 1 works, but option 2 and 3 result in the subject and body fields not being pre-filled, when gmail is selected.

Comment: In the latest android(i.e 10) versions, only the custom URI method is working.

Comment: First approach will not work well, as `appendQueryParameter` will remove the recipient part. More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12035226/485986

Comment: `ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(activity)...` is now deprecated. Use  `new ShareCompat.IntentBuilder(activity)...` instead.

Comment: `ShareCompat` can handle attachments well: `addStream()` for every attachment Uri

Comment: option 1 does not work for me. It opens the mail client but doesn't show any mail id in the to field. but show the subject and body.

Answer (score 120):

This is quoted from Android official doc, I've tested it on Android 4.4, and works perfectly. See more examples at https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Email

```
public void composeEmail(String[] addresses, String subject) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:")); // only email apps should handle this
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, addresses);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Agreed! I'm surprised an answer like this is so far down the list. I guess it must have been a relatively recent change in the Android Docs.

Comment: Great! dependable one, it referred the 'Bible' of Android app developers.

Comment: The colon after mailto did the trick for me! I was using "mailto" instead of "mailto:"

Comment: Working on 5.1.1. The other options doesn't work for me.

Comment: nice solution :)

Comment: diddnt work correctly, both the email and subject data doesnt get populated in the gmail app

Comment: This is the only working answer. Be careful to set Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Intent.ACTION_SEND won't work with "mailto:"

Comment: According to the docs, only `ACTION_SENDTO` is supposed to show just email apps, but it also doesn't allow to have attachments. How come? What if I do want to send attachments, and I wish to send only to email apps?

Comment: `EXTRA_EMAIL` not working for me so I used `Uri.parse("mailto: " + myEmail)`

Answer (score 110):

A late answer, although I figured out a solution which could help others:

### Java version

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:abc@xyz.com"));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send feedback"));
```

### Kotlin version

```
val emailIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO).apply { 
    data = Uri.parse("mailto:abc@xyz.com")
}
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send feedback"))
```

This was my output (only Gmail + Inbox suggested):

[image: my output]

I got this solution from the [Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Email) site.

Comment: For me it was important that there is no space between `mailto` and the email: `mailto:abc@xyz.com`

Comment: Great Solution ,  i had the same requirement, thanks a lot.!!!!

Comment: Excellent solution. Would you be great if you could show how to add Subject and Body as well.

Answer (score 48):

This works for me:

```java
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { "me@somewhere.com" });
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "My subject");

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Email via..."));
```

Most importantly: Use the [ACTION_SENDTO](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_SENDTO) action rather than the [ACTION_SEND](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_SEND) action. I've tried it on a couple of Android 4.4 devices and:

1. It correctly limits the chooser pop-up to only display email applications (Email, Gmail, Yahoo Mail etc); and
2. It correctly inserts the email address and subject into the email.

Answer (score 37):

Try:

```
intent.setType("message/rfc822");
```

Comment: He's right, I tried it and offers [Drive, Email, Gmail, Skype], this should be the "Right answer"

Comment: Using the MIME type to perform a send operation is a bad idea, because you're basically instructing Android to provide a list of apps that support sending a file of type `message/rfc822`. That's **not** the same as sending an e-mail. Use the `mailto:` protocol instead, because that's what e-mail clients actually understand.

Answer (score 37):

This is the proper way to send the e-mail intent according to the [Android Developer Official Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Email)

Add these lines of code to your app:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);//common intent 
intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:")); // only email apps should handle this
```

Optional: Add the body and subject, like this

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Your Subject Here");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "E-mail body" );
```

You already added this line in your question

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"hello@example.com"});
```

This will be the recipient's address, meaning the user will send you (the developer) an e-mail.

Comment: @barnacle.m Thank you! It's also one of the more simple methods. The problem is that my answer doesn't get enough upvotes :(

Comment: It's because there's a lot of similar answers, but this one points out the official Android documentation on the matter.

Comment: I was unable to send email address. I fixed it like this 
intent.data = Uri.parse("mailto:somemail@xyz.com")

Comment: This didn't work until I changed `Intent.ACTION_SEND` to `Intent.ACTION_SENDTO`.

Comment: I always forget that the 'Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL' value needs to be an Array, otherwise it will not populate the "To" field in the mail client (at least the Gmail App client anyway, haven't tested others)

Answer (score 30):

Finally come up with best way to do

```
String to = "test@gmail.com";
String subject= "Hi I am subject";
String body="Hi I am test body";
String mailTo = "mailto:" + to +
        "?&subject=" + Uri.encode(subject) +
        "&body=" + Uri.encode(body);
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse(mailTo));
startActivity(emailIntent);
```

Comment: This is the only answer that worked out of all to get: To, From, Subject, Body.

Answer (score 19):

Works on all android Versions:

```
String[] to = {"email@server.com"};
Uri uri = Uri.parse("mailto:email@server.com")
  .buildUpon()
  .appendQueryParameter("subject", "subject")
  .appendQueryParameter("body", "body")
  .build();
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
emailIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_EMAIL, TO);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
```

Updated for Android 10, now using Kotlin...

```
fun Context.sendEmail(
  address: String?,
  subject: String?,
  body: String?,
) {
  val recipients = arrayOf(address)
  val uri = address.toUri()
    .buildUpon()
    .appendQueryParameter("subject", subject)
    .appendQueryParameter("body", body)
    .build()
  val emailIntent = Intent(ACTION_SENDTO, uri).apply {
    setData("mailto:$address".toUri());
    putExtra(EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    putExtra(EXTRA_TEXT, body);
    putExtra(EXTRA_EMAIL, recipients)
  }
  val pickerTitle = getString(R.string.some_title)
  ContextCompat.startActivity(this, Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, pickerTitle, null)
}
```

...after updating to API 30, the code did not fill the subject and body of the email client (e.g Gmail). But I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59365539/4411049):

```
fun Context.sendEmail(
  address: String?,
  subject: String?,
  body: String?,
) {
  val selectorIntent = Intent(ACTION_SENDTO)
    .setData("mailto:$address".toUri())
  val emailIntent = Intent(ACTION_SEND).apply {
    putExtra(EXTRA_EMAIL, arrayOf(address))
    putExtra(EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject)
    putExtra(EXTRA_TEXT, body)
    selector = selectorIntent
  }
  startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, getString(R.string.send_email))) 

}
```

Comment: Your answer helped me. Thanks

Comment: the damn mail is not accepted / empty from gmail in the java version.

Comment: dont use java version that is outdated. added new to support all android versions.

Answer (score 16):

If you want only the email clients you should use `android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL` with an array. Here goes an example:

```
final Intent result = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
result.setType("plain/text");
result.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { recipient });
result.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
result.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);
```

Comment: nope, Still brings up lots of other apps - a lot more than `ACTION_SENDTO`

Answer (score 11):

The following code works for me fine.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("message/rfc822");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"abc@gmailcom"});
Intent mailer = Intent.createChooser(intent, null);
startActivity(mailer);
```

Answer (score 10):

### Edit: Not working anymore with new versions of Gmail

This was the only way I found at the time to get it to work with any characters.

doreamon's answer is the correct way to go now, as it works with all characters in new versions of Gmail.

Old answer:

---

Here is mine. It seems to works on all Android versions, with subject and message body support, and full utf-8 characters support:

```
public static void email(Context context, String to, String subject, String body) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("mailto:" + Uri.encode(to));
    if (subject != null) {
        builder.append("?subject=" + Uri.encode(Uri.encode(subject)));
        if (body != null) {
            builder.append("&body=" + Uri.encode(Uri.encode(body)));
        }
    }
    String uri = builder.toString();
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse(uri));
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: +1 `Uri.encode` is the correct way to go. But why calling it two times for subject and body?

Comment: So, doing the encoding yourself is just a bad idea. Better use a proper Intent with the necessary extras, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/15022222

Comment: For me this is the best answer because other solutions work correctly only with some of the email apps. This one works with every email app that I tested.

Answer (score 9):

None of these solutions were working for me. Here's a minimal solution that works on Lollipop. On my device, only Gmail and the native email apps appear in the resulting chooser list.

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO,
                                Uri.parse("mailto:" + Uri.encode(address)));

emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email via..."));
```

Answer (score 9):

Most of these answers work only for a simple case when you are not sending **attachment**. In my case I need sometimes to send attachment (ACTION_SEND) or two attachments (ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE).

So I took best approaches from this thread and combined them. It's using support library's `ShareCompat.IntentBuilder` but I show only apps which match the ACTION_SENDTO with "mailto:" uri. This way I get only list of email apps with attachment support:

```
fun Activity.sendEmail(recipients: List<String>, subject: String, file: Uri, text: String? = null, secondFile: Uri? = null) {
    val originalIntent = createEmailShareIntent(recipients, subject, file, text, secondFile)
    val emailFilterIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse("mailto:"))
    val originalIntentResults = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(originalIntent, 0)
    val emailFilterIntentResults = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(emailFilterIntent, 0)
    val targetedIntents = originalIntentResults
            .filter { originalResult -> emailFilterIntentResults.any { originalResult.activityInfo.packageName == it.activityInfo.packageName } }
            .map {
                createEmailShareIntent(recipients, subject, file, text, secondFile).apply { `package` = it.activityInfo.packageName }
            }
            .toMutableList()
    val finalIntent = Intent.createChooser(targetedIntents.removeAt(0), R.string.choose_email_app.toText())
    finalIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, targetedIntents.toTypedArray())
    startActivity(finalIntent)
}

private fun Activity.createEmailShareIntent(recipients: List<String>, subject: String, file: Uri, text: String? = null, secondFile: Uri? = null): Intent {
    val builder = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(this)
            .setType("message/rfc822")
            .setEmailTo(recipients.toTypedArray())
            .setStream(file)
            .setSubject(subject)
    if (secondFile != null) {
        builder.addStream(secondFile)
    }
    if (text != null) {
        builder.setText(text)
    }
    return builder.intent
}
```

Comment: This looks like it could be useful; any chance of getting it in Java?

Comment: Kotlin is very similar to Java, you should be able to copy paste and just change few things.

Comment: wont work on android 11 due to query package limitation

Comment: @Omkar T It did work for me on Android 11, with a provider tag in my Android Manifest. There is good info in the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider).

Comment: A huge benefit to this strategy is that it not only works with multiple attachments, but it is an extension on Activity which can easily be used in multiple projects.

Answer (score 9):

From [Android developers docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common#ComposeEmail):

```
public void composeEmail(String[] addresses, String subject) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:")); // only email apps should handle this
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, addresses);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

in **Kotlin** if anyone is looking

```
val emailArrray:Array<String> = arrayOf("travelagentsupport@kkk.com")
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO)
intent.data = Uri.parse("mailto:") // only email apps should handle this
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, emailArrray)
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Inquire about travel agent")
if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Following Code worked for me!!

```
import android.support.v4.app.ShareCompat;
    .
    .
    .
    .
final Intent intent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder
                        .from(activity)
                        .setType("application/txt")
                        .setSubject(subject)
                        .setText("Hii")
                        .setChooserTitle("Select One")
                        .createChooserIntent()
                        .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET)
                        .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

activity.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 5):

This works for me perfectly fine:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:" + address));
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "E-mail"));
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to ensure that your intent is handled only by an email app (and not other text messaging or social apps), then use the `ACTION_SENDTO` action and include the "mailto:" data scheme. For example:

```
public void composeEmail(String[] addresses, String subject) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:")); // only email apps should handle this
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, addresses);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

I found this in https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Email

Comment: For me the test if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) is always null, any idéea why ?

Answer (score 3):

Using `intent.setType("message/rfc822");` does work but it shows extra apps that not necessarily handling emails (e.g. GDrive). Using `Intent.ACTION_SENDTO` with `setType("text/plain")` is the best but you have to add `setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"))` to get the best results (only email apps). The full code is as follows:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:IT@RMAsoft.NET"));
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Email from My app");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Place your email message here ...");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send Email"));
```

Comment: Perfect soultion

Answer (score 3):

Please use the below code :

```
try {
    String uriText =
            "mailto:emailid" +
                    "?subject=" + Uri.encode("Feedback for app") +
                    "&body=" + Uri.encode(deviceInfo);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriText);
    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
    emailIntent.setData(uri);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email using..."));
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
    Toast.makeText(ContactUsActivity.this, "No email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is how i manage to do it in kotlin :

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO)
intent.data = Uri.parse("mailto:")

intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, emailAddress)
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, emailSubject)
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, emailBody)
context.startActivity(intent)
```

Hope it can help

Answer (score 2):

If you want to target Gmail then you could do the following. Note that the intent is "ACTION_SENDTO" and not "ACTION_SEND" and the extra intent fields are not necessary for Gmail.

```
String uriText =
    "mailto:youremail@gmail.com" + 
    "?subject=" + Uri.encode("your subject line here") + 
    "&body=" + Uri.encode("message body here");

Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriText);

Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
sendIntent.setData(uri);
if (sendIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
   startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Send message")); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am updating Adil's answer in Kotlin,

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO)
intent.data = Uri.parse("mailto:") // only email apps should handle this
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, Array(1) { "test@email.com" })
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject")
if (intent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
    startActivity(intent)
} else {
    showSnackBar(getString(R.string.no_apps_found_to_send_mail), this)
}
```

Comment: This fails even when Gmail is on the app.

Comment: @AndroidDev in which device you are facing the issue?

Answer (score 2):

**Kotlin:**

```
val email: String = getEmail()
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO)
intent.data = Uri.parse("mailto:$email" )
startActivity(intent)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String sendEmailTo = "abc@xyz.com";
String subject = "Subject";
String body = "Body";
            
Uri uri = Uri.parse("mailto:"+sendEmailTo+"?subject="+subject+"&body="+body);
    
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
```

This worked for me. This will only show the mailing application in the intent chooser.

Additionally:
One problem that i faced with this method is I was unable to add space in the suggestions and body text.
So, to put spaces in the suggestion or body text then replace the space with `%20`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try this: `intent.setType("plain/text");`

I found it [here](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-send-email-your-application). I've used it in my app and it shows only E-Mail and Gmail options.

Comment: "plain/text" shows Bluetooth, Skype etc. Checkout the desired output in Android Market app. Steps are listed in the question.

Comment: Using the MIME type to perform a send operation is a bad idea, because you're basically instructing Android to provide a list of apps that support sending a file of type `plain/text`, and that isn't even a valid MIME type. That's **not** the same as sending an e-mail. Use the `mailto:` protocol instead, because that's what e-mail clients actually understand.

Answer (score 1):

Compose an email in the phone email client:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("plain/text");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { "some@email.address" });
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "mail body");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, ""));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
boolean success = EmailIntentBuilder.from(activity)
        .to("support@example.org")
        .cc("developer@example.org")
        .subject("Error report")
        .body(buildErrorReport())
        .start();
```

use build gradle :

```
compile 'de.cketti.mailto:email-intent-builder:1.0.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use, and it works for me:

```
//variables
String subject = "Whatever subject you want";
String body = "Whatever text you want to put in the body";
String intentType = "text/html";
String mailToParse = "mailto:";

//start Intent
Intent variableName = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
variableName.setType(intentType);
variableName.setData(Uri.parse(mailToParse));
variableName.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
variableName.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);

startActivity(variableName);
```

This will also let the user choose their preferred email app. The only thing this does not allow you to do is to set the recipient's email address.

Comment: You are missing a `"` on the 2nd line.

Answer (score 1):

> This code is working in my device

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
mIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
mIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[] {"mahendrarajdhami@gmail.com"});
mIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(mIntent, "Send Email Using..."));
```

Comment: it only opens Gmail and Email in my device

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts("mailto", email, null));
if (emailIntent.resolveActivity(context.getPackageManager()) != null) {
    context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send Email..."));
} else {
    Toast.makeText(context, "No apps can perform this action.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**SEND TO EMAIL CLIENTS ONLY - WITH MULTIPLE ATTACHMENTS**

There are many solutions but all work partially.

**mailto** properly filters email apps but it has the inability of not sending streams/files.

**message/rfc822** opens up hell of apps along with email clients

so, the solution for this is to use both.

1. First resolve intent activities using mailto intent
2. Then set the data to each activity resolved to send the required data

```
private void share()
{
     Intent queryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse("mailto:"));
     Intent dataIntent  = getDataIntent();

     Intent targetIntent = getSelectiveIntentChooser(context, queryIntent, dataIntent);
     startActivityForResult(targetIntent);
}
```

Build the required data intent which is filled with required data to share

```
private Intent getDataIntent()
{
        Intent dataIntent = buildIntent(Intent.ACTION_SEND, null, "message/rfc822", null);

        // Set subject
        dataIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, title);

        //Set receipient list.
        dataIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, toRecipients);
        dataIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, ccRecipients);
        dataIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_BCC, bccRecipients);
        if (hasAttachments())
        {
            ArrayList<Uri> uris = getAttachmentUriList();

            if (uris.size() > 1)
            {
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
                dataIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
            }
            else
            {
                dataIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris.get(0));
            }
        }

        return dataIntent;
}

protected ArrayList<Uri> getAttachmentUriList()
{
        ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList();
        for (AttachmentInfo eachAttachment : attachments)
        {
            uris.add(eachAttachment.uri);
        }

        return uris;
}
```

Utitlity class for filtering required intents based on query intent

```
// Placed in IntentUtil.java
public static Intent getSelectiveIntentChooser(Context context, Intent queryIntent, Intent dataIntent)
{
        List<ResolveInfo> appList = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(queryIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);

        Intent finalIntent = null;

        if (!appList.isEmpty())
        {
            List<android.content.Intent> targetedIntents = new ArrayList<android.content.Intent>();

            for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : appList)
            {
                String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo != null ? resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName : null;

                Intent allowedIntent = new Intent(dataIntent);
                allowedIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName(packageName, resolveInfo.activityInfo.name));
                allowedIntent.setPackage(packageName);

                targetedIntents.add(allowedIntent);
            }

            if (!targetedIntents.isEmpty())
            {
                //Share Intent
                Intent startIntent = targetedIntents.remove(0);

                Intent chooserIntent = android.content.Intent.createChooser(startIntent, "");
                chooserIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, targetedIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));
                chooserIntent.addFlags(android.content.Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

                finalIntent = chooserIntent;
            }

        }

        if (finalIntent == null) //As a fallback, we are using the sent data intent
        {
            finalIntent = dataIntent;
        }

        return finalIntent;
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for this answer, this is the only one which works for me to also include attachments.. Don't know why this case a down vote co I'm putting one up vote here..

Answer (score 1):

There is an easy solution also with ACTION_VIEW:

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        Uri data = Uri.parse("mailto:customer@something.com?subject=Feedback");
        intent.setData(data);
        startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

I almost used all of the answers here on android 11 but they did not work properly. some of them does not place the mailto on its required field and some other don't even work at all. so I did read the new documentation and found that mailto emails should be in an array so what worked for me finally is here.
Anyways thanks for all the answers, they did help after all.

```
//mail me
findViewById<TextView>(R.id.mailme).setOnTouchListener { _, _ ->
    try {
        val mail: Array<String> = arrayOf("somemail@cc.com")
        val mailme = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO).apply {
            data = Uri.parse("mailto:")
            putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, mail)
            putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hey We Need Your Help With This Issue.")
            putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "At Logs Calculator, We Need Your Help !")
        }
        startActivity(mailme)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private void sendEmail() {
        String version = getString(R.string.android_version_not_found);
        String appVersion;

        try {
            version = "Version Android: " + Build.VERSION.RELEASE + " (API " + Build.VERSION.SDK_INT + ")";
            PackageInfo packageInfo = requireActivity().getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(requireActivity().getPackageName(), 0);
            appVersion = "Version App: " + packageInfo.versionName;
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            appVersion = getString(R.string.app_version_not_found);
        }

        String deviceName = Build.MODEL; // Get the device name
        String subjectTemplate = getString(R.string.contact_us_subject_template);
        String subject = getString(R.string.contact_us_subject_template);

        String bodyTemplate = getString(R.string.contact_us_body_template);
        String topic = getString(R.string.problem_description) + "\n\n" + version + "\n" + appVersion + "\nDevice: " + deviceName;
        String body = String.format(bodyTemplate, topic);

        String email = getString(R.string.contact_us_email);
        String mailtoUrl = "mailto:" + email + "?subject=" + Uri.encode(subject) +
                "&body=" + Uri.encode(body);

        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse(mailtoUrl));

        try {
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, getString(R.string.choose_email_client)));
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), getString(R.string.install_email_client_before_sending), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_EmailInfor"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:autoLink="web|email"
        android:linksClickable="true"
        android:text="@string/support_emailt"
        android:textColor="@color/appBlue"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_14sdp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground" />
```

Answer (score 0):

use Anko - kotlin

```
context.email(email, subject, body)
```

Answer (score 0):

With Kotlin, works with Gmail :

```
val i = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO).apply {
    type = "text/html"
    data = Uri.parse("mailto:")
    putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, arrayOf(email))
    putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject)
    putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, subject)
}
if (packageManager != null && i.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
    startActivity(i)
}
```

If anyone find a solution to display the message too...

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you need to open default email app to view the inbox without creating a new letter, in this case it will help:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_APP_EMAIL);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

follow this to the letter and you should have no issues

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common#ComposeEmail

make sure you pass an array in the EXTRA_EMAIL field while using ACTION_SENDTO