# Android Intent.createChooser not working for Intent.ACTION_SEND

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an android application where I am loading office locations into a `ListView` via a custom `Adapter`.

Inside each `ListViewItem` I have an `ImageView` which is an email icon and I have bound a custom `OnClickListener` to the `ImageView` which should allow the user to create an email to send to an office location.

I want the user to be able to select from the email applications which are on their device so I have used `Intent.CreateChooser()` in my custom `OnClickListener` like so:

```
    private class EmailOnClickListener implements OnClickListener {
        private Context context;
        private String email;

        public EmailOnClickListener(Context context, String email) {
            this.context = context;
            this.email = email;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setType("message/rfc822");
            intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {email});
            intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Test Subject");

            context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send mail..."));
        }
    }
```

I have been binding my custom `OnClickListener` via my custom `Adapter` as follows:

```
    ImageView email = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.btnEmail);
    email.setOnClickListener(new EmailOnClickListener(context, contact.getEmail()));
```

I am currently testing this on a HTC Desire HD which is Android 2.3 and even though I have Gmail as well as default Mail on my device, when I tap the email icon, it does not show me a chooser but it just loads straight into Gmail.

Why doesn't the chooser show?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer from this question (look for the answer by doreamon) [Send Email Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701634/send-email-intent)

for quick reference I have changed the code in my `onClick` method to the following:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts("mailto", email, null));
intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Test Subject");

context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send mail..."));
```