# Package the K-9 Mail App in another app

Tags: android, email

Basically I am trying to develop an app which will contain the email option among other options. When the user clicks on the Email button the K-9 Mail would launch inside of the parent app as another activity. Is this possible to achieve? If yes, then can you give me some hints. Thanks!

Comment: I would like to implement this. I am rebranding k9 for my uni email and want to use it in another app. No luck so far though

Answer (score 0):

You can use Email Intent, a la [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701634/send-email-intent), to achieve what I believe you're suggesting.

If you want to run K-9 Mail *inside* your app -- well, I don't know if that's possible, but I doubt it.

Comment: Yes i want to run the K-9 Mail inside my app

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run the email app without your app, this is not possible. However you can launch an intent to send an email and the K-9 app would be an option.

Comment: Is there any open source implementation which i can incorporate like the way i want?