# Intent Object - Action to send Email

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to send Email.I use this code.Now i have a problem

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
```

I can not understand what is  **Intent.ACTION_SEND** ? why use it? What's return **Intent.ACTION_SEND** ??Please help me.Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

> `ACTION_SEND` deliver data to someone else. Who the data is being
>   delivered to is not specified; it is up to the receiver of this action
>   to ask the user where the data should be sent.

For more informations : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND

For sending an email with that intent, you may have a look to :

[Send Email Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701634/send-email-intent)