# Email Dialog like Call Dialog in Android

Tags: android

We can open `Call Dialler` with Number passed in Intent. So like that, Is there any way to open `Email Dialog` with to Email ID ?

When User Clicks on Specific `TextView`, I want to show dialog itself to user like Send Email Using and after choosing appropriate option like `Gmail`, It opens `Gmail` with filling to Email Address.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Send Email Intent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701634/send-email-intent)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    emailIntent.setType("plain/text");

    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
            new String[] { "emailadd" });
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "text");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
```