# Send link to Whatsapp via Android Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, whatsapp

I'm trying to send a text message with a link from my android app to chat applications like Whatsapp or SMS message.

These apps don't accept text/html type as an Intent type and when I'm using text/plain type my message is being sent with the subject only and without the message's body.

I've seen apps that can share links via Whatsapp like Chrome and Dolphin Browser apps.

Here is my code:

```
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void sendMessage(String trip) {
        final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Trip from Voyajo");
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml("I've found a trip in Voyajo website that might be interested you, http://www.voyajo.com/viewTrip.aspx?trip=" + trip));
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send to friend"));
}
```

Comment: For me (latest WhatsApp on a Nexus 5, Android 5.0), both `EXTRA_SUBJECT` and `EXTRA_TEXT` are included in the shared message, in the form "Subject - Extra text". What I did: use only `EXTRA_TEXT`, putting the whole message, including urls, in that. But use  *plain text*, skip all HTML.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
@JavascriptInterface
    public void sendMessage(String trip) {
        final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Trip from Voyajo");
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml("I've found a trip in Voyajo website that might be interested you, http://www.voyajo.com/viewTrip.aspx?trip=" + trip));
        emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send to friend"));
}
```

here i just change position of  `emailIntent.setType("text/plain");` this line and it works.
you get your link in messaging app body email app body.but here you can get subject text only in Mail apps not in messaging app but you can get your link in body so achive your goal...

Thats it...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. From what I understand, The above code will only trigger whatsapp. Can I add somehow Whatsapp to the chooser activity with the other apps that accept text/plain like Gmail, SMS and so?

Comment: just remove  waIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp"); line from above code thats it...

Comment: also remove if condition and else part :)

Comment: That would be similar to my code, which results in message being sent without the link when sending via whatsapp...

Comment: Also I've tried your code and I get the same problem - the message's body isn't sent just the subject...

Comment: have you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701634/send-email-intent and  http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sending_email.htm links.

Comment: I've resolved my problem by omitting the Html.fromHtml call. Thanks!