# Convert string to Link

Tags: android, hyperlink

I have given a 'Share With' option in my application. And when the user clicks on that, lets suppose user selects, 'Share With' WhatsApp or Twitter, I am showing a custom message template that appears by default in the message, just when WhatsApp or Twitter launches. I have a message and a link in that. I want to make that link clickable. Right now both message and link are coming as string. Can anyone help me in achieving that.

I will simplify:

Current: "Welcome to Google https ://google.com"

Required: "Welcome to Google" https://google.com (link should appear in blue and should be clickable)

My code is below:

```
private void redirectUserToShareWith() {
    Intent referIntent = new Intent();
    referIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    String dynamicUrl = "https://google.com";
    String linkedText = String.format("<a href=\"%s\">link</a> ", dynamicUrl);
    referIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mCtx.getString(R.string.message_body) + Html.fromHtml(linkedText));
    referIntent.setType("text/plain");
    mCtx.startActivity(referIntent);
}
```

Comment: Look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/9852184/8844009

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: textview hyperlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9852184/android-textview-hyperlink)

Comment: Its not a text view guys. Its just a string. I am directly setting string as a message. Half part of message is normal string, rest is link.

Comment: If this is not a textview, where you are showing this message?

Comment: I am showing the message in a kind of template. I am passing the message through intent.

Comment: check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25243143/send-link-to-whatsapp-via-android-intent

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display HTML in TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116162/how-to-display-html-in-textview)

Answer (score 0):

check this, below code works for me

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                "Hey check out my app at: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.osmanaslanoglu.kizane");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```