# Android open send mail intent and receive callback when user send mail

Tags: android, email, android-intent

I need to open the send mail intent([Send Email Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701634/send-email-intent)) and know if the user has really sent the email.

The feature is a "Invite your friend to use the app" and I need to let the user inform the address to send the email.

The approach of using send mail intent is the better because the user can edit the e-mail subject and body and use his prefered email client.

But if there is no way to know if the user has really sent the e-mail, I will embed the e-mail client inside my app.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to open the send mail intent(Send Email Intent) and know if the user has really sent the email.

[`ACTION_SEND` does not offer a result](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND), so there is no requirement for any `ACTION_SEND` implementation to tell you what specifically was done with the data the user elected to share.