# Issue with Intent.ACTION_SEND in Lotus Notes Traveler App

Tags: android, android-intent, lotus-notes, email-client

I am developing an Android application which sends emails using Intent.ACTION_SEND. I am sending EXTRA_EMAIL, EXTRA_CC, EXTRA_BCC, EXTRA_SUBJECT along with it.  My problem with Lotus noted is that, the above mentioned parameters are not getting populated in Lotus Notes while other email clients are working fine.

I am aware that in the [Android developers site](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html), it clearly states that

**"Optionally, you can set some standard extras for the intent: EXTRA_EMAIL, EXTRA_CC, EXTRA_BCC, EXTRA_SUBJECT. If the receiving application is not designed to use them, it simply ignores them."**

But there is nothing I can find to prove that Lotus Notes Traveler is one of such kind.

It will be nice if anyone can provide solution...

Thanks in advance,

Heyjii

Comment: Looks like you have actually proven that. If it does not react on those extras, then it is not designed to use them. It might be that Lotus Notest suppurts its own extras, if it is documented anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test if any app responds particular intent type then you can do that using `adb shell am` command

Examples:

- Sending `intent` with action `view` by specifying the action and data uri

  ```
  adb shell am start -a "android.intent.action.VIEW" -d "http://developer.android.com"
  ```
- Sending `intent` with action `send` with an string extra by specifying the action, mime type and an extra string

  ```
  adb shell am start -a "android.intent.action.SEND" --es "android.intent.extra.TEXT" "Hello Android" -t "text/plain"
  ```

Try doing this for required actions and include required extras.

Comment: Thanks @Praveen for the prompt response. I have tested it and ensured that Lotus Notes listens to the Action_Send intent. But my actual problem is it is not pre populating the bcc and cc fields even though the other intent extras are working fine...

Comment: Send bcc and cc extras from commandline using adb if you  get same result then it means your app works fine but it is the problem with Lotus app

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your time. I got a solution which works in Lotus Notes Traveler as well. I have used the solution provided by **becomputer06** for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701634/send-email-intent) stackoverflow question.

Here it is....

```
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    buffer.append("mailto:");
    buffer.append("stackoverflow@stackoverflow.com");
    buffer.append("?subject=");
    buffer.append("App Name");
    buffer.append("&body=");
    String uriString = buffer.toString().replace(" ", "%20");

    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse(uriString)),
```

It uses a URI scheme to send the data and all the fields are getting populated...

Thanks  and Regards,

Heyjii