# Failure to handle UTF-8 characters in Android 4.0 +

Tags: android, android-intent, utf-8

I developed one Android application and set minSDK 14 (android 4.0 +). i want use `UTF-8` characters (**RTL language**) . but when show this text instead of letters, question mark shows!!!

See this images to understand my mean : [Image 1](http://i.cubeupload.com/p32iyI.png) ------ [Image 2](http://i.cubeupload.com/GoqSC2.png)

An example of my codes :

```
mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
String mobile_model = Build.MODEL;
String mobile_factory = Build.MANUFACTURER;
String mobile_android = Build.VERSION.RELEASE;
Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"tellfa.group@gmail.com"});
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "5دقیقه - انتقاد و پیشنهاد");
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "متن مورد نظر شما" + "\n\n\n\n\n" + "------------------" +
                    "\n" + "لطفا موارد زیر را پاک نکنید" +
                    "\n" +"مدل گوشی شما : " + mobile_model +
                    "\n" + "شرکت سازنده گوشی : " + mobile_factory +
                    "\n" + "نسخه اندروید شما : " + mobile_android);
            email.setType("message/rfc822");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "سرویس دهنده را انتخاب کنید"));
```

how to fix it problem?

Comment: maybe this code will help you : https://fabioangelini.wordpress.com/2011/08/04/converting-java-string-fromto-utf-8/

Comment: @ItzikSamara, tnx for your help. but don't work me :(

Comment: ok use uri.encode(...) solution found here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701634/send-email-intent

Comment: @ItzikSamara, Thank you, but I could not find good solutions.You can modify the code, and give me? its very important for me

Comment: @ItzikSamara, i edit such as this : String share_title = Uri.encode("سرویس دهنده را انتخاب کنید"); . but dose not work again . shows for example : %3F%3F%3F...

Comment: @dashakhe.goli %3F is a question mark so even the string constant is broken. I suspect the .java file is not in UTF-8. (In the screenshot you posted, the .java files were not visible.)

Comment: @StenSoft, how to set .java in UTF-8 ? can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You must use the code to **change the encoding of the text**

**for example :**

```
String txt = URLEncoder.encode("5دقیقه - انتقاد و پیشنهاد", "UTF-8");
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, txt);
```

use this code for all Persian put extras