# Why is not connection to the client?Android

Tags: java, android, email-client

I am trying to create an activity to send an email. I am using an Intent Object "Action send" to launch the email client.

However is not detecting the email client, this is the first time I am doing this, please help. What is wrong with my code?

```
public class email extends Activity {

    private Button send;
    DBHelper mydb1;
    private ListView obj;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mydb1 = new DBHelper(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.email_display);
        ArrayList array_list = mydb1.getAllCotacts();
        ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array_list);

        obj = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2);
        obj.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);


            send  =(Button) findViewById(R.id.send_button);

            send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

                                    {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(View v) {
                                            try {
                                                Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                                                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"myemail@gmail.com"});
                                                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
                                                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "HEY");
                                                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, "example@gmail.com");
                                                emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
                                                startActivity(emailIntent);
                                            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
                                                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(email.this, "Sorry, no email client found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                                                toast.show();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }

            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are there any apps on your test device that can receive an intent of MIME type `message/rfc822`?

Comment: Could you give more information about the error please? MimeType seems to be the problem, http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sending_email.htm make a look at it

Comment: [See this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701634/send-email-intent)

Answer (score 0):

> On your button click :

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"youremail@yahoo.com"});          
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "message");
emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Choose an Email client :"));
```

As per your code change

```
startActivity(emailIntent);
```

to

```
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Choose an Email client :"));
```

OR

try with ,

Instead use a **ACTION_SENDTO**, providing the **mailto: Uri**

```
  intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse("mailto:"));
```

This may helps you.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    i.setType("text/plain");
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"abc@gmail.com"});
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "body");
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, new String[] { "edf@gmail.com" });
    try {
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

**Edit**

Try using:

```
 i.setType("text/plain");
```

Comment: That trough me another error "No apps can perform this action" the mail is setup in my emulator and already tried with plain text

Comment: @CarlosSiverioGonzalez i am updating my answer. Please check.