# Forgot Password Form

Tags: android, authentication, passwords

I want to add a Forgot Password form for when the user clicks Forgot Password. I already have one in PHP. I am using a MySQL database.

Should it go to the Forgot Password Activity?

Can anyone help me or have a sample code?

Comment: why not create forgot password also in PHP ?

Comment: Paste your code of from and event from where you want to navigate

Comment: Please attempt the problem yourself. StackOverflow isn't a code writing service.

Answer (score 0):

To send an email, you can use this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/html");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "emailaddress@emailaddress.com");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "I'm email body.");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send Email"));
```

P.S. taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701634/send-email-intent)

Comment: i havent problem to use intent,,,my problem in forgot password method,,,how can i send an email in android studio using php and mysql?

Comment: Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

check this website [here](https://www.learn2crack.com/2016/04/android-login-registration-php-mysql-reset-password.html)

```
<?php
 require_once 'DBOperations.php';
 require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

 class Functions{

private $db;
private $mail;

public function __construct() {

    $this -> db = new DBOperations();
    $this -> mail = new PHPMailer;

}

public function resetPasswordRequest($email){

    $db = $this -> db;

    if ($db -> checkUserExist($email)) {

        $result =  $db -> passwordResetRequest($email);

        if(!$result){

            $response["result"] = "failure";
            $response["message"] = "Reset Password Failure";
            return json_encode($response);

        } else {

            $mail_result = $this -> sendEmail($result["email"],$result["temp_password"]);

            if($mail_result){

                $response["result"] = "success";
                $response["message"] = "Check your mail for reset password code.";
                return json_encode($response);

            } else {

                $response["result"] = "failure";
                $response["message"] = "Reset Password Failure";
                return json_encode($response);
            }
        }
    } else {

        $response["result"] = "failure";
        $response["message"] = "Email does not exist";
        return json_encode($response);

    }
}

public function resetPassword($email,$code,$password){

    $db = $this -> db;

    if ($db -> checkUserExist($email)) {

        $result =  $db -> resetPassword($email,$code,$password);

        if(!$result){

            $response["result"] = "failure";
            $response["message"] = "Reset Password Failure";
            return json_encode($response);

        } else {

            $response["result"] = "success";
            $response["message"] = "Password Changed Successfully";
            return json_encode($response);

        }
    } else {

        $response["result"] = "failure";
        $response["message"] = "Email does not exist";
        return json_encode($response);

    }
}

public function sendEmail($email,$temp_password){

    $mail = $this -> mail;
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = 'your.email@gmail.com';
    $mail->Password = 'password';
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
    $mail->Port = 465;

    $mail->From = 'your.email@gmail.com';
    $mail->FromName = 'Your Name';
    $mail->addAddress($email, 'Your Name');

    $mail->addReplyTo('your.email@gmail.com', 'Your Name');

    $mail->WordWrap = 50;
    $mail->isHTML(true);

    $mail->Subject = 'Password Reset Request';
    $mail->Body    = 'Hi,<br><br> Your password reset code is <b>'.$temp_password.'</b> . This code expires in 120 seconds. Enter this code within 120 seconds to reset your password.<br><br>Thanks,<br>Learn2Crack.';

    if(!$mail->send()) {

        return $mail->ErrorInfo;

    } else {

        return true;

    }
}

public function sendPHPMail($email,$temp_password){

    $subject = 'Password Reset Request';
    $message = 'Hi,nn Your password reset code is '.$temp_password.' . This code expires in 120 seconds. Enter this code within 120 seconds to reset your password.nnThanks,nLearn2Crack.';
    $from = "your.email@example.com";
    $headers = "From:" . $from;

    return mail($email,$subject,$message,$headers);

}
}
```