# Android Sending Email

Tags: android

I Wrote This Code To Send An Email But Give Me " No App Can Perform This action " Error ?!! Can Any One Help Me .!

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Button startBtn;
Intent chooser = null , emailIntent = null;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    startBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendEmail);
    startBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            sendEmail();
        }
    });
}
```

protected void sendEmail()

```
    {
        String[] TO = {"a.gadelkareem94@gmail.com"};
        emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, TO);
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Hello");
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Thanks For Your Job");
        emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
        emailIntent.setPackage("com.Gmail");
        chooser = Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send Email");
        startActivity(chooser);
    }
```

}

but no emails Send

Answer (score 1):

You should use `intent.setType("text/plain");`

We can use `"message/rfc822"` instead of "`text/plain"` as the MIME type. However, that is not indicating "only offer email clients" -- it indicates "offer anything that supports message/rfc822 data". That could readily include some application that are not email clients.

message/rfc822 supports MIME Types of .mhtml, .mht, .mime

as alredy answered here: [Send Email Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701634/send-email-intent)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues with your snippet.

1. The one that's responsible for the "No app can perform this action" is `emailIntent.setPackage("com.Gmail")`. This will only consider apps with the application ID "com.Gmail" as target for the intent. However, "com.Gmail" is not the application ID of the Gmail app. You shouldn't limit the selection anyway. So let's just drop this line.
2. ACTION_SEND is the generic Share action. This will work with email apps, but there's a better way: use ACTION_SENDTO. With ACTION_SENDTO the only input is a `mailto` URI. One that includes the recipient, subject and text from your example looks like this: `mailto:a.gadelkareem94@gmail.com?subject=Hello&body=Thanks%20For%20Your%20Job`
3. Users tend to use only one email app and set that one as default. By using `Intent.createChooser()` you make them have to manually choose their email app every time (assuming there's more than one installed).

Considering all this we end up with:

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:a.gadelkareem94@gmail.com?subject=Hello&body=Thanks%20For%20Your%20Job"));
try {
    startActivity(emailIntent);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    //TODO: Display message that no email app was found
}
```

To make all this less painful I wrote the library [EmailIntentBuilder](https://github.com/cketti/EmailIntentBuilder). You can use it like this:

```
EmailIntentBuilder.from(context)
        .to("a.gadelkareem94@gmail.com")
        .subject("Hello")
        .body("Thanks For Your Job")
        .start();
```

I also wrote a blog post explaining all of this in more detail: [Sending Email using Intents](http://cketti.de/2016/01/08/sending-email-using-intents/).