# How to pass string array to android email intent

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to send an email programmatically in kotlin.

Here's my code, which I translated from a java example I found on the Web.

```
package com.example.emaildemo

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

class MainActivity: AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState:Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val editTextTo:EditText  = findViewById(R.id.editText)
        val editTextSubject:EditText = findViewById(R.id.editText2)
        val editTextMessage:EditText = findViewById(R.id.editText3)
        val button1:Button = findViewById(R.id.button)

        button1.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener{

          val to = editTextTo.getText().toString()
          val subject = editTextSubject.getText().toString()
          val message = editTextMessage.getText().toString()

          val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
          val addressees = arrayOf(to)
          intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, addressees)
          intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject)
          intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message)
          intent.setType("message/rfc822")
          startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Email Sending App :"))
       })
   }
}
```

It seems to work correctly, except that the "TO" field isn't copied into the user's email app.  The java code said:

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{TO});
```

and the android developer [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html) say that Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL is "A string array of all "To" recipient email addresses."  How should I define the `addressees` variable?

EDIT: I've discover that if I hard code my email address,

```
val addressees = arrayOf("me@email.com")
```

then the app works as expected.  When I get to the email app, my address is in the "To:" field, and I can send mail to myself.  If, however, the I type the same address in the program, it doesn't show up in the email client.  Moreover, when I look at it under the debugger, the intent shows exactly the same values both ways.  Curiouser and curiouser.

**EDIT2**

Here is my XML file.  (Somehow I can't get the first two lines indented correctly.)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:text="To"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:text="Subject"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:text="Message"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:lines="4"
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Click Here To Send Email from android application programmatically"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="44dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: what's wrong about you? Kotlin `arrayOf<String>(...)` is equivalent to Java `String[]`.

Comment: @holi-java Then why doesn't this work?

Comment: :), I'm not an android developer, and you didn't give any information what happened that nobody know why didn't work. it seems to your mime-type is wrong, maybe this can helped you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701634/send-email-intent

Answer (score 5):

Your **TO** statement looks right, I don't think you need to be explicit (i.e, using `arrayOf<String>(to)`).

**EDIT**

Based on your last update, `to` is not being recognized as a `String`.  The following code works...

```
            val to = "person@gmail.com"
            val subject = "Test"
            val message = "Test"

            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
            val addressees = arrayOf(to)
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, addressees)
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject)
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message)
            intent.setType("message/rfc822")
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send Email using:"));
```

The call to `editTextTo.getText().toString()` is returning a builder or something other than a true `String`.  Instead try calling `arrayOf(to.toString())`

**EDIT2**

Here is an example of code that works, i.e., fills in the "To" field in the email app.

```
package com.x.edittextexp

import android.content.Intent
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val button: Button = findViewById(R.id.button)
        val editTextTo: EditText = findViewById(R.id.editTextTo)

        button.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            val to = editTextTo.getText().toString()
            val subject = "Test"
            val message = "Test"

            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
            val addressees = arrayOf(to)
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, addressees)
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject)
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message)
            intent.setType("message/rfc822")
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send Email using:"));
        })
    }
}
```

And the xml looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:hint="person@gmail.com"
    android:id="@+id/editTextTo"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="BUTTON"
    android:id="@+id/button"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

As you can see, the differences are trivial, but this works and yours doesn't.  I would suspect the problem is in your XML file.  Could you post it?

Comment: sorry, I meant `intent.setType("*/*")`

Comment: :), you can use backslash `\\` to escape markdown symbols.

Comment: The "TO:" field still comes up blank.  I'm going to have to try it on a different device, but I don't have one available just now.

Comment: using a debugger, make sure that `to` actually has a value in it

Comment: @saulspatz - ok then, try using to.toString()

Comment: This didn't work, but it gave me the right idea.  See my answer.

Comment: @Les Posted my xml file.

Comment: I took your code verbabim, changed only the package name and it works properly, "To" populates.  Next idea is versions.  I am running with Android Studio 3.0, Canary 8, building with minSdkVersion=23, targetSdkVersion=26, targetSdkVersion=26.

Answer (score 1):

I tried Les's suggestion of using `arrayOf(to.toString())`, but android studio grayed out `.toString()` indicating that it knew it was a string already.  Then I tried being more explicit:

```
val addressees: Array<String> = arrayOf(to)
```

and it worked!  I don't understand this at all.  It doesn't seem like kotlin should have any trouble with the type inference.  Perhaps some guru will see this and explain it; I'd be interested and grateful.

Comment: my last edit uses the same construct, and Kotlin has no problem interfering the type.

Comment: I had it defined as an array of CharSequence and that wasn't working.  Thanks for the tip.