# Sending data with multiple attachments with email intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a `FeedbackActivity.java` activity which takes feedback from user with multiple attachments (upto 3 images as attachments).

I am using following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);     
intent.setType("message/rfc822");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, emails);                   //emails is an Array of 'String' type
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);                //subject is a String
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text)                       //text is a String
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris); //uris is an ArrayList of 'Uri' type
                                                              //uris stores all Uri of images selected

if(intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null){
    startActivity(intent);
}
else {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Not Good", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Now this code works fine but the problem is that it shows all sorts of apps which support "message/rfc822" MIME type.

Image is shown below :

[image]

I only need to show the email client apps, I tried Uri.parse("mailto:"), but didn't workout and code always moves to else statement and shows the toast "not good".

I read the google documentation but it only shows simple cases.
I tried searching on the web. Many developers are using `intent.setType("*/*")` or `intent.setType("text/plain")`. But they all too show apps other than email clients.

Please guide me.

And I wanted to ask in general,

Google documentations show simple examples which is good in a way, but how to learn really in depth on these kind of topics?

Thank you.

Comment: You can try the selector-and-chooser approach shown in https://stackoverflow.com/a/59365539/115145 for `ACTION_SEND` -- I have not tried this for `ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE`.

Comment: Yeah, this really works! selectorIntent with action `Intent.ACTION_SENDTO` and emailIntent with action `Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE`. Works like charm!!

Comment: You might want to post an answer with the code that you wind up using. Glad to hear that it is working for you!

Comment: I don't  understand why people downvote without any reasons! This is really bad for StackOverflow! Totally demotivating for new-comers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So here, we will be using two intents: `selectorIntent` and `emailIntent`. `selectorIntent` is what the `emailIntent` will use as to show available apps. code:

```
Intent selectorIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
selectorIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));

final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, emails);
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
emailIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
emailIntent.setSelector(selectorIntent);
if(emailIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null){
    startActivity(emailIntent);
}
else {
    Snackbar.make(scrollView, "Sorry, We couldn't find any email client apps!", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Now it will choose only apps which are email client.

If there is only one email-client app in your phone than it will directly open that. And if no such application is there, than the code will show Snackbar given in the else part.

Answer (score -1):

Don't use Uri.parse, use **Uri.fromParts**

Do it like this:

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts("mailto","example@mail.com", null));
```

Comment: I want to send multiple attachments, so Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE is what i need to have, and Uri.fromParts() is somehow not detecting email clients when used with Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE