# send Email through Android Intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have tried to send Email through Android Intent by using below code

```
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent();

    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, EmailContent);
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, RecipientName );
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT , subject );
    sendIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
    sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

    Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(sendIntent , chooser_title );

    if (sendIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(chooser);
    }
```

In the email app the recipient details are not getting update whereas all the other details such as subject, body is getting updated with my input . Could you please suggest what needs to be done to resolve this .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Send Email Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701634/send-email-intent)

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass the EXTRA_EMAIL as string array.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts(
            "mailto","abc@gmail.com", null));
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Body");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email..."));
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment .I tried it but result is recipient address did not get updated in gmail app.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:-
Create String resource for recipients:-

```
    <string-array name="receipients">
    <item>mgf@kgf.co</item>
    <item>sdf@kgf.co</item>
</string-array>
```

and use this intent

```
     Intent gmailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        gmailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        gmailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, resources.getStringArray(R.array.receipients));
        gmailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,subject);
        gmailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, EmailContent);
        gmailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
            gmailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT);
        final PackageManager pm = context.getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
        final List<ResolveInfo> matches = pm.queryIntentActivities(gmailIntent, 0);
        ResolveInfo best = null;
        for (final ResolveInfo info : matches)
            if (info.activityInfo.packageName.endsWith(".gm") ||
                    info.activityInfo.name.toLowerCase().contains("gmail")) best = info;
        if (best != null)
            gmailIntent.setClassName(best.activityInfo.packageName, best.activityInfo.name);


        try {
           startActivity(gmailIntent);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.you_do_not_have_gmail_installed), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment .

Comment: There is no error . Seems everything successful but the External Gmail app does not get filled with the data provided in EXTRA_EMAIL value.Stack trace does not get generated since there is no crash. Can you please let me know if there is way still to capture the stack trace.

Comment: logical output : https://www.dropbox.com/s/9bdinjyrmfeoxkh/logat_output.pdf?dl=0