# How can I execute QR on android?

Tags: android, kotlin, qr-code

I have made a QR app, I want to be able to execute the QR code just like the standard camera on my phone does.

I have a template for sending email, sms, and for creating contact info etc. When scanning the QR from my phones standard camera it sends me to the correct client. For email it sends me to email client and for contact info it fills sends me to the contact app. Is this possible to do from my app as well ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Send Email Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701634/send-email-intent)

Comment: Sort of yes for email and if i do the parsing manually by myself
.But is there an easier approach because the QR could be something else;
website, email, sms, contact info, calendar event etc ..

Comment: I guess opening the link aka `startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(link)))` is satisfying enough, because intent filters of browsers/email apps/etc usually handle their required scheme

Comment: That did not work