# Android - Launching Google Navigation from an app

Tags: android, navigation

I am currently in progress of an android app, which takes some coordinates by the user (Starting point from gps and destination defined by the user)

I would like my app to launch the google navigation so that it can guide the user through these points. At a next step, I would like to give navigation more points (eg some points of interest) so that it will guide the user through a specific route containing all the points.

Is that possible? All that I find is no-documented practices and no examples. Is there anyone who has solved this problem? If not, can someone suggest some other navigation programm?

Thank you in advance,
George

Comment: see post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662531/launching-google-maps-directions-via-an-intent-on-android

Comment: These commands:
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + StartLon + "," + StartLat + "&daddr=" + DestLon + "," + DestLat));
startActivity(intent);
seems to work. But in the emulator I always get "no route found" (maybe this isn't supposed to work on emulator anyway. Gonna test it soon on a device)

Comment: you may try to use gps fix from DDMS and specify the current location ...incase that is the problem

Comment: You mean in terms of using the emulator? I gave virtual gps fix both from cmd (using the geo fix command) and the emulator control view of eclipse. The programm seems to receive the fix with no problem. It just gives "no route found" though. I'll update the post in some days that I will use it in a real device.

Answer (score 20):

You can certainly guide them to a single point:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=" +mLat+","+mLong));
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Not sure about setting way points might be some way to do it, I think the API is undocumented so use at your own risk. You could have your app in the background listening to the GPS information and have it prompt the user at certain points.

Comment: Yes I have used this, but is this documented (about the single point at least) or is there any risk in using it?

Comment: @george Have got it working for multiple number of points...I too faces issues doing similar thing.

Comment: how to set title??