# Can I pass an address to Google maps API for Android that will open Google maps with the requested address?

Tags: android, google-maps

I´m new to the Android world,

I want to write an application for Android that will receive a destination address from a central server, opening the Google maps  showing the routing from the current location to the requested destination.
There will be many clients (cellular phones).

I want to ask
1) Is it possible to do it with the Google maps API ?

2) Regarding Google map licensing, I read different answers in this forum and I´m not sure 
I understood, Is a Google map license required?

3) If anyone has worked with OpenGts, is it recommended as a server? and can it save data to a local database (e.g. MYSQL) 
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Yes, it's possible. The way I went when I worked on a Google maps project was that:

First, using the Google Maps for Android API, put a map in your application.

Using the GPS, detect your position. Then, just send a request to the Google Maps online API to generate you a path between your two location.

Google maps will then answer you with the encrypted path to use (use this algorithm to decrypt the path http://jeffreysambells.com/2010/05/27/decoding-polylines-from-google-maps-direction-api-with-java ).

Once this is done, do whatever you want with the path. Know that the easiest thing to do, is to create a polyline thanks to the path, and then display it on the map. If you want to do a real GPS, the easiest thing to do would be to use intents between the Google Navigation App and your informations ( [Android - Launching Google Navigation from an app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8559540/android-launching-google-navigation-from-an-app) )

2) For the integration of the map in your application, you have to request a Goole Maps for Android API key, that you can find in the Google Api Console : https://code.google.com/apis/console
For the Google Maps web service API, no key is required.

I let someone else answer to your 3).

More informations :

Google Maps API web service : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/webservices/?hl=fr

Introduction to Google Maps Android API v2 https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/

Google Maps for Android API http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

1) Of course. You can use Google Maps API Web Services: [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/webservices/). The web service give you a path described in json format, so you have to parse the result and draw the path on the map. You can use MapView for showing the path from source to destination. [Here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/hello-mapview) a tutorial from android developer site.

2) If you want know if you can use Google maps for commercial applications, the answer is that Google maps can be use for some commercial application. "not all commercial uses are allowed. If your site meets any of the following criteria you must use Google Maps API Premier" More details [here](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/maps/f0KajhPKQ9Y)

3) Yes, OpenGts supports Google Maps as you can see [here](http://opengts.sourceforge.net/)