# Android: Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps

Don't know if anyone can help me with this or if it's even possible. But I would like to open the standard maps application on a device from my own application showing the user's current location.

Any advice/tutorial where I can get information would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Shaw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this site: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html.

There's a simillar question here: [Launching Google Maps Directions via an intent on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662531/launching-google-maps-directions-via-an-intent-on-android)