# Optimal route between two points

Tags: android, google-maps

Is there any way to draw optimal route(considering traffic) between **two** geopoints using Android Google maps API?

Comment: As far as I know, Google Maps' routing system does not take into account traffic. It can tell you about traffic on a route, but it will not optimize your route around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but you'll need to do some work with the Google Maps API to get it going. Here's a link to a tutorial that explains how:

http://www.anddev.org/google_driving_directions_-_mapview_overlayed-t826.html

Alternatively you can just link from your app to the Maps app, and let Maps show the directions & route.
[Launching Google Maps Directions via an intent on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662531/launching-google-maps-directions-via-an-intent-on-android)