# Opening maps by default

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent

I have an application based on google maps, in which I am opening route planner using intent. But, when application starts, it prompts dialog box to user with option of default browser and maps. But, I want that when application starts, it should open in maps by default. Below I am posting my code.

```
public class RoutePlannerActivity extends MapActivity {
public static final String TAG = "Route planner";
MapView mapView;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
            Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=28.6667,77.2167&daddr=28.5700,77.3200")); 
    startActivity(intent);
}//onCreate

protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Route displayed");
    return true;
}//isRouteDisplayed
}//class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get rid of the dialog you can give the intent a hint as to which package you want to use. Before the startActivity() add this:
`intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");`
Credits to [this previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662531/launching-google-maps-directions-via-an-intent-on-android). I suggest searching before posting.

Answer (score 1):

try this code for rid of the dialog..

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?" + "saddr=23.0286423,72.5580967&daddr=23.0559485,72.5423041"));
        intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps","com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
        startActivity(intent);
```