# How to programmatically launch map application in android to show direction?

Tags: android, dictionary, direction, driving-directions

My client asked me to show directions between two location. Therefore he wants that our application should launch map application of android and show direction between two location. I could not find the solution for this problem.

Therefore can anybody tell me how to programmatically launch map application from our current application and show directions between two location in Android.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried this?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662531/launching-google-maps-directions-via-an-intent-on-android

Comment: I want to launch Phone's map application first. Then show the route in that. Isnt it possible?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=20.344,34.34&daddr=20.5666,45.345"));
startActivity(intent);
```