# Launch directly the directions on Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I want to launch the Google Maps app from my android application with the driving directions view.

I gone through the following posts but they don't serve my purpose.

[Launch Google Maps to show road directions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5740606/launch-google-maps-to-show-road-directions)

[How to programmatically launch map appliction in android to show direction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10877656/how-to-programmatically-launch-map-appliction-in-android-to-show-direction)

I tried the following code...

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
            Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&daddr=51.448,-0.972"));
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.google.android.apps.maps", 
            "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity"));
        startActivity(intent);
```

Which gives me the following view,

[image]

Then I need to click 'Get Directions' button to get the following view,

[image]

And then I need to click 'DIRECTIONS LIST' to get the following view,

[image]

Is there a way to directly launch the 3rd view (as above) from my android application?

Answer (score 0):

Yes You can directly open direction view Using **google.navigation**.

Just pass Destination address and it will give direction from current location to destination address:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=destination address"));
startActivity(intent);
```