# Android - Save a location to Maps

Tags: android, maps

I am planning to develop an app, to scan (using NFC, similar to QR codes) a geo-location/ address and save it to "My Places" on "Maps" and also an option to get directions to this location. Do I need a Maps API key? Do I use Google places API?

Is there a sample which does something similar to this?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Regards
Surekha

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/) and will need an API key from [Google API Console](http://code.google.com/apis/console/), but that said I'm not aware of a way to add places to a user's My Places... 
You could forward them to the Google Maps app with the place's details...

Comment: For getting directions from A to B, I referred this [link.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662531/launching-google-maps-directions-via-an-intent-on-android)