# Creating an intent to send my location data to a navigation app installed on my android phone

Tags: android

I'm creating an app which obtains users location and location of various of interest. I need to add an intent to send the data of my location and the point's location to a navigation app. How do I achieve this?

Comment: @JermaineXu am completely lost. I have been going through andorid documentation and so far i have not come across anything usefull

Comment: After reading the question n:th time. It came to mind, do you even have access to the navigation app source code or any idea of the intents it uses?

Comment: thanks to @AdilSoomro I found the answer [here] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662531/launching-google-maps-directions-via-an-intent-on-android/2663565#2663565)

Comment: Please ignore the bounty its meant for another question

Comment: I don't know why this was marked down, it's a reasonable question even if poorly framed. If he knew exactly how to word the question he wouldn't need to ask it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
 Button map_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.map_btn);
        map_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = null, chooser;
                intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("geo:xx.xxxxxx,xx.xxxxxx"));
                chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent,"Lunch Map");
                try {
                    startActivity(chooser);
                }catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                    e.getCause();
                }

            }
        });
```

where xx.xxxxxx is your location.