# Launch google maps after clicking Marked

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I have got the following code, and what I want to do is to open "Google Maps" APP [How to go] to the marker I have set up:

```
// S E T   M A P   P O I N T        
    mLocationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);
    mapFragment = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
    map         = mapFragment.getMap();
    map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    map.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
    map.setOnMapClickListener(this);
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(latitude, longitude), ZOOM));
    map.clear();


    addressText = GetGeolocation.getgeocoder(Date_Accept.this, latitude, longitude);

    Marker marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
    .title(addressText)
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));

    marker.showInfoWindow();
```

How can I open "Google Maps" app to get the route to that point?

Answer (score 1):

you should be able to fire an intent with the maps url and let android handle it for you

[read about that here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662531/launching-google-maps-directions-via-an-intent-on-android)

Comment: It works fine, but I also would like to call new intent when marker title was clicked. DO you know how I should implement that?

Comment: implement a [OnMarkerClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener.html)