# Create a QR code which can then open an Android app

Tags: android, qr-code

My question is how could i create a program which could do the below things?

on given information, lets say and address. Then turn that information into a QR code which can be read by an app and launch a GPS map and search the address.

So, if I gave it the information: "Westminster, London SW1A 0AA" it would convert it into a QR code which upon being scanned would open a GPS map and search the address, so minimal interaction has to be done on the phone users part.

Comment: Please note that tags are not keywords.  Stuffing the tag list full of the same words that are in your question (qr-code, open, app) will not help categorize it.  Always be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You obviously would just map the url to your qr code.
The link below says its unofficial in the US.  The geocoder api is metered meaning you only get so many free hits on it a day.  Making a QRcode that's api in itself.

http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=20.344,34.34&daddr=20.5666,45.345

[Launching Google Maps Directions via an intent on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662531/launching-google-maps-directions-via-an-intent-on-android)