# How to Navigate with Google Maps directly from my application

Tags: android, google-maps

Good day,

I am trying to use Google maps to navigate my app user to a certain address / location. From what I have found on the net so far I have tried the following:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
                        Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=-36.181,27.949&daddr=-36.174732,27.949770"));
                    startActivity(intent);
```

Now this is all good and well it opens up Google maps, but it ask me a jolly lot of things before I can actually get to the navigation.

- 1: It fist asks me to select a trip
- 2: It then shows me the trip
- 3: I then have to click the little arrow head (Navigate Button)

Then only does it begin Navigation.

Is there not a way for me to specify in my intent to use the first route and to just start **navigating immediately/automatically?**

On a second note, Once I have reached my destination or I want to go back/cancel, the back button needs to take me back to my application, right now it then goes back to showing me the route, then I click back again and it says are you sure you want to exit navigation.

Or can I maybe listen for an Intent that Maps publishes once you have reached the destination. So as The user gets to the destination my application will come into focus again?

Answer (score 3):

Try this method

```
String urlAddress = "http://maps.google.com/maps?q="+ lat + ","+ lng + "("
                + your_location_name + ")&iwloc=A&hl=es";
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse(urlAddress));
        startActivity(intent);
```

This will open the google map on given valid lat, lng values and will show your_location_name as the place name.

Comment: Could you please clarify, is your_location_name the destination address? and the log and lat your current position?

Comment: This will open the google map on given valid lat, lng values and will show your_location_name as the place name.

Comment: But this does not automatically start navigation?

Comment: @Zapnologica sorry I miss understood. please have a look on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662531/launching-google-maps-directions-via-an-intent-on-android

Answer (score 1):

```
// try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.

String uri = "http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&hl=es&saddr=-36.181,27.949&daddr=-36.174732,27.949770";
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: The produces the same results as my initial one.

Comment: when you try to show route via default google map app then we follow the his step not are and if you don't wan such kind steps then you have to develop your custom root implementation code.

Answer (score 0):

```
String uri = "google.navigation:q=%f, %f";
Intent navIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(String                  .format(Locale.US, uri, customerDropOffLatLng.latitude, customerDropOffLatLng.longitude)));
navIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
startActivity(navIntent);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please refrain from code only answers; provide some context/explanation. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer