# Android Intent Google Maps just show route, no navigation

Tags: android

I need to know the params, how an intent has to be done, to show just the routing in text (not the route on map or start navigation).

```
Uri.parse("maps.google.com?saddr" + address)
```

The code above start the navigation and showing the route on the map.

Is there someting like ...route?...

Comment: Here is the [a link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662531/launching-google-maps-directions-via-an-intent-on-android)! where you will find the solution.thank u.

Comment: Thats not what I am searching for. If you use...
intent.setData(Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=" + address));
... then the navigation is startet. I just need the step before. That means, I need the user choose if he wants by car, bike or walking.