# Google Maps Directions intent for bicycle

Tags: android, google-maps, directions

When using an intent to launch navigation via Google Maps Directions, is there a way to specify you want a route for walking / bicycle?

Answer (score 4):

See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/

> By changing the mode and avoid parameters, the initial request can be
>   modified to return directions for a scenic bicycle journey that avoids
>   major highways.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Toronto&destination=Montreal&avoid=highways&mode=bicycling&key=API_KEY
```

> Travel Modes
>
> When you calculate directions, you may specify the transportation mode
>   to use. By default, directions are calculated as driving directions.
>   The following travel modes are supported:
>
> driving (default) indicates standard driving directions using the road
>   network. walking requests walking directions via pedestrian paths &
>   sidewalks (where available). bicycling requests bicycling directions
>   via bicycle paths & preferred streets (where available). transit
>   requests directions via public transit routes (where available). If
>   you set the mode to transit, you can optionally specify either a
>   departure_time or an arrival_time. If neither time is specified, the
>   departure_time defaults to now (that is, the departure time defaults
>   to the current time). You can also optionally include a transit_mode
>   and/or a transit_routing_preference.

You can use it like this (code snippet from https://stackoverflow.com/a/2663565/1843331)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
    Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=20.344,34.34&daddr=20.5666,45.345"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set route using intent like this:

```
val gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("google.navigation:q="+destintationLatitude+","+destintationLongitude + "&mode=b")
val mapIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri)
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps")
startActivity(mapIntent)
```

Here, "mode=b" is for bicycle.

We can set driving, walking, and bicycling mode by using:

- d for driving
- w for walking
- b for bicycling

You can find more about intent with google maps 
[here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/android-intents).

**Note**: If there is no route for the bicycle/car/walk then it will show you **"Can't find the way there"**