# Android - Can I create a custom shortcut to app that is not mine

Tags: android, shortcut

I would like to create a shortcut to a very specific action within an app. The app I'm talking about tracks the views of my shows. In this app it is possible to mark an episode as watched. I want to do this marking for my favourite show from the home screen. Just a tap on the shortcut and it will mark the next unwatched episode However, this app is not mine. Will it be possible to create a shortcut like this for an app that isn't mine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless that app already supports that action as a shortcut, then no.

For example, for Google Maps, use can use [this intent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2663565/4015623) to launch the app and open directions:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
    Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=20.344,34.34&daddr=20.5666,45.345"));
startActivity(intent);
```

If the app that you want to launch doesn't already support some intent with parameters to mark the episode as watched, then there is no way to do that without getting the app developer to add that functionality.

Answer (score 0):

If this app is not yours and if you are not allowed to do so, then you **absolutely can't**.

But if the developer of that app allows you to do this and adds necessary functionality to handle this shortcut action, then this is very much possible.

Hope my answer has solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the original URL with tiny URL, call tinyurl api using this link: http://tinyurl.com/api-create.php?url= and append youre URL that you want.

Second, you use that new link in your application (intent extras). remember the tinyurl is permanent, depends from your original URL.