# How to launch a car navigation to location from the app

Tags: android

You might find my question silly, but I can't find anything about it. I don't even know how to call it to get the tutorial I need.

I want simply my application after clicking a button to start for example Waze and pass on the address that the user can navigate to it.

If you could just direct me what should I look for it will be great.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662531/launching-google-maps-directions-via-an-intent-on-android

Comment: Thanks @Barend. Instead of GM I'd like to launch another app passing on the adress.

Comment: If you want to launch any other app I don't have an answer. If you want to launch Waze specifically: https://www.waze.com/about/dev

Comment: That's enough. Thank you very much @Barend. If you would post your comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to launch the Waze app specifically, you can use the URL scheme at [waze.com/about/dev](http://waze.com/about/dev) to launch the app. I don't know of any Intent protocol or URL scheme that's shared by any and all navigation apps.